# How to make my form send the submitted info to my email

Tags: php, html, email, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to figure out how to get my contact form in my website to send to my email when someone submits.

I am using Google Clouds Instance and hosting on google domains. I tried to go with a process_form.php but it doesn't work even when I installed php already using the SSH in the instance.

I went with a simpler one but it doesn't work as well. It doesn't seem to be the same as previously I tried years ago to do and submit this Contact Us form.

Heres my HTML code for contact us form:

```
   <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2 class="text-dark">Get in Touch</h2>
                <p class="text-dark">For inquiries, bookings, or any questions, feel free to contact us:</p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-dark">
                    <li><strong>Phone:</strong> +1 (123) 456-7890</li>
                    <li><strong>Email:</strong> mymail@gmail.com</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="text-dark">Connect with us on social media:</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <a href="#" class="text-dark me-3"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-dark me-3"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-dark me-3"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-dark me-3"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Right Section - Contact Form -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">  
                 <form action="mailto:mymail@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="contact" class="form-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="date" class="form-label">Preferred Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="destination" class="form-label">Fishing Destination</label>
                        <select class="form-select" id="destination" name="destination" required>
                            <option value="">Select Destination</option>
                            <option value="Destination 1">Destination 1</option>
                            <option value="Destination 2">Destination 2</option>
                            <option value="Destination 3">Destination 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="anglers" class="form-label">Number of Anglers</label>
                        <select class="form-select" id="anglers" name="anglers" required>
                            <option value="">Select Number of Anglers</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="rent" class="form-label">Need to rent fishing rods?</label>
                        <select class="form-select" id="rent" name="rent" required>
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="rodsets" class="form-label">Number of Rod Sets</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rodsets" name="rodsets" min="0">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
```

How do I really get this working? I spent 4 hours on this already but to no avail. Please help.

I tried with process_form.php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $contact = trim($_POST["contact"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $date = trim($_POST["date"]);
    $destination = trim($_POST["destination"]);
    $anglers = trim($_POST["anglers"]);
    $rent = trim($_POST["rent"]);
    $rodsets = trim($_POST["rodsets"]);

    // Set the recipient email address
    $to = "mymail@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject
    $subject = "New Contact Form Submission";

    // Build the email content
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Contact Number: $contact\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
    $email_content .= "Preferred Date: $date\n";
    $email_content .= "Fishing Destination: $destination\n";
    $email_content .= "Number of Anglers: $anglers\n";
    $email_content .= "Need to rent fishing rods: $rent\n";
    $email_content .= "Number of Rod Sets: $rodsets\n";

    // Build the email headers
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email
    if (mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Redirect to the thank you page if the email is sent successfully
        header("Location: index.html");
    } else {
        // Set a 500 internal server error response if the email failed to send
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
} else {
    // Set a 403 forbidden response if the form submission method is not POST
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
?>
```

This doesn't work too. My main contact us form was previously linked to process_form.php. It was successfully actually and went to index.html.

I don't know what to do anymore. This is the last hurdle. I should have went with web hosting companies that might be easier to use. It was so difficult to use SSH on Google clouds and I had a hard time at first, figuring out how to upload my index.html etc etc, using google maps api etc etc. Now this is just my last hurdle and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work" please? What happens, how far through your code does it get?

Comment: Your form action should point to your email processing PHP (`process_form.php`) rather than a `mailto` link, surely?

Comment: You may also find problems if you are using your form-fillers email address as your "from" address. To allow that to work, whichever mail server you are using would need to be configured to send emails from any domain, which is generally called Open Relay and not a good thing to have. I wouldn't expect the Google mail servers to do it. Use your own email address as the "from" address, and set the "reply-to" header to the enquirers address.

Comment: If you're using the Gmail servers to send your emails, you'll probably have to enable TLS and SMTP authentication - it's been a while, I can't remember exactly but there's plenty of documentation on the subject. You might have more success using something like the PHPMailer library.

Comment: Im sorry for the lack of details, it doesn't work when i pointed my email processing php as in my php codes, it was sent successfully as i was redirected back to index.html. I am trying to find out how to enable TLS and SMTP, it is so taxing and I can't even find out where to do it. I am able to integrate PHPMailer with my host?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to fix :

(A) You need to change the form tag of your HTML form from

```
<form action="mailto:mymail@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

to

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="post">
```

(B) and change this line in PHP from

```
 $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
```

to

```
    $encoding = "utf-8";
    $email_headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=".$encoding." \r\n";
    $email_headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
    $email_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $email_headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \r\n";
```

(C) As commented, please consider changing the "from email" (in the $email_headers) to an email address of which the PHP web server will be regarded as a valid outgoing mail sender (e.g. with proper SPF record and/or DKIM signed), otherwise it may be regarded as spam by recipient email servers

Last but not least,

1. You may have noticed that I have used `Content-type: text/plain;` in the headers (because you are using `\n` as new line), but usually we will use `Content-type: text/html` because in that case you can use the HTML syntax to compose a better email contents (in that case you need to change all `\n` to `<br>` in your email contents)
2. instead of mail() function in PHP, you may choose to use `PHPMailer` which is a rather robust mail sending library to do the job